# False "proof" that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, fake-proofs

About to fall asleep, I came up with the following "proof" that $\mathbb{R}\cap[0,1]$ is countable:

> For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let the set $S_k$ be the set containing ever positive real number less than one with decimal expansion consisting of $k$ or fewer digits. Then
>   $$\mathbb{R} \cap [0,1] = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty S_k.$$
>   But because each $S_k$ is finite, $\mathbb{R}\cap[0,1]$ is countable as it is the countable union of finite sets.

After thinking about it for a couple of minutes, I don't see what's wrong with it. Please tear it apart so I can sleep.

Comment: There are already uncountably many with the digits $0$ and $1$.

Comment: All this proves is that most numbers have non-terminating decimal expansions (infinitely many digits), as there are only countably many with terminating expansions.

Comment: Tip for the future, if you're about to fall asleep and you came up with a proof, write it down for yourself, and examine it in the morning.

Comment: Terminating decimals in (the decimal system) can be expressed as fractions (integer) in their lowest terms in which the denominator has only the prime factors $2$ or $5$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very important misunderstanding here, which is the idea that "arbitrarily long" is still less long than "infinitely long". As others have pointed out, your set only contains the numbers with finitely many decimal digits. You can have as many finitely many digits as you want, true. But you cannot have infinitely many digits.

Because, okay, suppose that you had a thing with infinitely many digits. If it's really in the union, it has to live at some level of the union (in some $S_k$). But by definition, it doesn't live in any of the $S_k$. So it cannot not be in the union.

Answer (score 1):

Your set $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty S_k$ contains only rational numbers, but $\mathbb{R} \cap [0,1]$ contains also irrational numbers, so $$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty S_k \neq \mathbb{R} \cap [0,1]$$

Comment: And $\bigcup_k S_k$ does not even contain all the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose some irrational is in your $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty S_k$.
Let $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty S_k$.

OK, $a\in\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ means, that there exists at least one set $b_i$ for which it is true that $a\in b_i$.

But in your example every $S_k$ contains numbers with finite digits in their decimal expansion. So there is no such $S_k$, that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} \in S_k$.

Comment: This already works with rationals like $\frac13$.